# Hibernate execute IN query on an enum data type column

Tags: hibernate, enums

Currently, I have a table that has a column which has a datatype enum. My question is can I execute a IN query on this column?

For example:

```
enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE, GAY };
Table Student (
  String name;
  Gender gender;
)
```

Can I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE gender IN ('MALE', 'FEMALE');
```

Note that I use string as the parameter for in, but I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [('MALE')] did not match expected type [Gender]
```

Is there a workaround on this issue?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Comment: Since when is gay a gender??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since string values are not recognised, execute the following code (Assuming you have used Enum with default [EnumType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE gender IN (0,1);
```

If using EnumType.String

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.gender=:g1 or s.gender=:g2");
query.setParameter("g1", Gender.MALE);
query.setParameter("g2", Gender.FEMALE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using EnumType.String, so I can only compare with String.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about that earlier but my parameter is dynamic string. But I'll give it a try parse the string and convert to the appropriate enum value. Thanks.