# How to set enum as parameter in hibernate native sql

Tags: sql, hibernate, enums

I have a this field in my pojo class

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="CAT_TYPE", unique=false, nullable=false)          
private CategoryType type;
```

In my Dao, I want to get a list of category depending on the type by this query:

```
String hql = "SELECT * FROM Category as c WHERE c.status='ACTIVE' and c.cat_type=:type";
    SQLQuery query = currentSession().createSQLQuery(hql);  
    query.addEntity(Category.class)
        .setParameter("type", type)
        .setFirstResult(index)
        .setMaxResults(max);
    List<Category> listOfCat = query.list();
```

The problem I have is that it can't not extract the resultSet.

But if I change the query to :

```
String hql = "SELECT * FROM Category as c WHERE c.status='ACTIVE' and c.cat_type='BOOKS'";
    SQLQuery query = currentSession().createSQLQuery(hql);  
    query.addEntity(Category.class)
        .setFirstResult(index)
        .setMaxResults(max);
    List<Category> listOfCat = query.list();
```

It works perfectly. So how can I set a parameter for enum?

Comment: these may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067225/hibernate-execute-in-query-on-an-enum-data-type-column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388622/querying-on-enums-method-in-hiberate-criteria-api

Comment: why you are using native SQL instead HQL?